# Is the Entity Framework Code First Migrations bound to specific DBMS?

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-migrations

Update: after I deleted and recreated migrations again SQL Server, no errors. So it *seems* that initial provider is encoded somewhere in the model snapshot.

Update:

[Created video to visualize the problem](https://1drv.ms/v/s!AnuGAVUQT6yqjMBkruis_zh6WK2pZw)

I wasn't aware of this, but is it seems the *Entity Framework Code First Migrations* is bound to specific DBMS. I used in my demo application SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0 and I am migrating it to SQL Server 2014 Express LocalDB.

The database schema in SQL Server is created correctly, but when I try to read or write to database I get following error

> No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0'.

I don't use SQL Server CE anywhere now, all NuGet packages are uninstalled, provider is removed from `App.Config`.

*app.config*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework"
             type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
             requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <connectionStrings configSource="ConnectionStrings.config" />
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"
                type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

*ConnectionStrings.config*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<connectionStrings>
  <clear/>
  <add name="CarRentalDb" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=CarRentalDb;Integrated Security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

*CarRentalDbContext.cs*

```
public class CarRentalDbContext : DbContext
{
    public CarRentalDbContext()
        //only used until development, will not be checked in
        : base(@"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=CarRentalDb;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new CarRentalDbInitializer());
    }

    public CarRentalDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new CarRentalDbInitializer());
    }
}
```

*dbo._MigrationHistories*

[image: dbo._MigrationHistories]

Now when I remove the *dbo._MigrationHistories* table, error is gone. Do I need recreate the migration to address SQL Server instead of SQL Server CE?

*NewCustomerIsCreated.cs*

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void NewCustomerIsCreated()
    {
        var customerLastName = CustomersLastNameToBeDeleted;

        //Arrange
        var systemUnderTest = new CarRentalBusinessLayer();
        var customerToBeCreated = _autoFixture.Build<CustomerModel>()
                                              .Without(property => property.CustomerId)
                                              .With(property => property.CustomerType, CustomerModel.Consumer)
                                              .With(property => property.LastName, customerLastName).Create();
        var expectedResult = customerToBeCreated;

        //Act
        systemUnderTest.CreateNewCustomer(customerToBeCreated.FirstName, customerToBeCreated.LastName, customerToBeCreated.DateOfBirth, customerToBeCreated.Street, customerToBeCreated.City, customerToBeCreated.Postcode,
            customerToBeCreated.CustomerType);

        //Assert
        Customer actualResult;
        using (var carRentalDbContext = new CarRentalDbContext(_connectionString))
        {
            actualResult = carRentalDbContext.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.LastName == customerLastName);
        }
        Assert.IsTrue(actualResult != null && expectedResult.LastName == actualResult.LastName);
    }
```

Comment: "Now when I remove the dbo._MigrationHistory table, error is gone." - This does not make sense. Does EF actually access the database? What is the initializer? However, I know EF has some issues updating the references. Are you sure all connections are SqlConnections, and the specified connection string points to the correct provider?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Yes you are right it make no sense, maybe I'm making some mistake but I'm not aware of this.I double check now the connection string which points correct to provider, I will update the question to be more clear.

Comment: the base constructor takes the connection string/DbConnection,ContextOwnsConnection. What happens when you use base(new SqlConnection(connectionString),true)? And what is CarRentalDbInitializer()?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I'll check it with the default constructor, still confused where is stored that I used SqlServer Ce before

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I added the video to visualize the problem. I removed also the default constructor which make obviously no change

Comment: what does the testmethod do? what is the initializer? is the created database SQLCE or SQL Server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122611/discussion-between-anton-kalcik-and-devilsuichiro).

Answer (score 0):

**OP's Feedback :**

> After I recreated migration no error. It really seems that provider is
>   encoded somewhere in the model snapshot.

**Original Answer :**

Yes,definitely you must do that.That means you have to `delete` the data on the `__MigrationHistory` table and need to `recreate` it.

If you see the below image,you can see the `ProductVersion` column is there.That is the cause for your run time error.

[image]

**Update :** It's an EF version.

```
 <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net461" />
```

Comment: But what exactly *ProductVersion* means?

Comment: ProductVersion there is the EF version used.

Comment: Please see the `Update` section.

Comment: However, I don't see how this database would interfere with the DbConnection - I mean, it isnt even targeted until the first Db call is executed.

Comment: @Sampath So it's the EF version of *EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact* I used before?

Comment: Aha..How can it be ? you told you deleted it no ? this may be the EF 6.x version no ?

Comment: this is the pure EF version used for this migration. the provider is not encoded there, as it is used to communicate to the database and not important for migrations. the only fact important for comparing databases/migrations is the EF version, as this determines the model for database created from modelBuilder.

Comment: @Sampath I deleted the NuGet packages of SQLServer CE but not recreated the migration. cs, resx and designer files are still the same. They were created when SQLServer CE was still used.

Comment: are you using `DB first` approach or what ?

Comment: @Sampath Yes I'm using DB First approach

Comment: @Sampath Created the video to visualize the problem. See update section in my question.

Comment: can you change the `Version=6.0.0.0` to `version=6.1.3` and test again ?

Comment: @Sampath Version of what?

Comment: here `<section name="entityFramework"
             type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
             requirePermission="false" />`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122612/discussion-between-anton-kalcik-and-sampath).

Comment: I have updated my post with your feedback.hope you'll accept the solution just for the time being.if you'll have better solution in the future, you can accept it at that time.it's better if you can close this thread. @AntonKalcik

Comment: @Sampath My last update and also yours doesn't answer my initial question, it is only assumption.

Comment: yes,that is why I have mentioned `just for the time being`.If you'll have better solution then you can accept it.It's not nice to keep post open like this hence you have some kind of workaround. sometimes we cannot find out the perfect solutions.At that time we have to satisfy with this kind of workarounds.That is my thought.